# MikroTik Hotspot External login page vs. RADIUS server

Tags: hotspot, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I am fairly new to MikroTik RouterOS and I was wondering if the following logic is correct:

When configuring Hotspot feature of a MikroTik router with External login page as explained [here](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/HotSpot_external_login_page), with the login page being a custom PHP/ASP/etc. hosted on the web, when user successfully authenticates on the said page, how does the web page then inform the MikroTik router about successful authentication? By setting a cookie? What I am trying to achieve is to have a website that hosts a separate database of usernames, and a login page on this website that the MikroTik router's Hotspot feature would redirect to when connection is established and authenticate the users there. I understand that using a RADIUS server would do the same but I am trying to build this using custom database of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have finished your login process, your webpage must redirect the user to the Mikrotik controller, like in this PHP example:

```
  $body = "<html><body onload='connexion.submit()'>";
  $body .= "<form name='connexion' action='https://[Your_Controller_IP]/login' method='post'>";
  $body .= " <input type='hidden' name='popup' value='false'>";
  $body .= " <input type='hidden' name='username' value='$username'>";
  $body .= " <input type='hidden' name='password' value='$password'>";
  $body .= "</form>";
  $body .= "</body></html>";
  echo $body;
  die();
```